# Java autocompletion in Vim with Eclim

Tags: eclipse, vim, eclim

It seems Vim is unable to find my Eclim files by searching for an older Eclim folder, although the entire Eclim-installation went smoothly. When running

```
:PingEclim
```

I am presented with the error

**Could not locate file> /Applications/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclim_2.2.7/bin/eclim**

The content of /Applications/Eclipse/plugins is as follows:

```
~ # ls /Applications/eclipse/plugins | ack -i eclim                                                                                                                                                                              
org.eclim.core_2.3.2
org.eclim.jdt_2.3.2
org.eclim.vimplugin_2.3.2
org.eclim.wst_2.3.2
org.eclim_2.3.2
```

Obviously it is searching for version 2.2.7, which is wrong.
*Eclipse version: **4.3.1 Kepller Service Release 1***

*Vim version:* **7.4**
Eclim version: **2.3.2**

I do not know why it searches in the faulty location, and I do not know how to change it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the problem arose due to me having remnant files from an earlier Eclim installation in my home directory.

Apparently Eclim registers (and keeps, new instances are simply appended) 

used Eclim instances in a file:

```
~/.eclim/.eclimd_instances
```

In this file I found two lines; one for an outdated Eclim installation path, and one for the current. By removing the obsolete line the plugin now loads properly and connection is achieved.